# How to simplify this block diagram and obtain transfer function C(s)/R(s)

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, block-diagram

I can only simplify the two blocks below. Please help me to simplify the rest. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of hints to get you started: -

[image]

Comment: Yes, It does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here, Let's start with the simplification that you have mentioned already and then proceed step by step.
[image]
The resultant will look as seen below. Now the second step is to realize that the two adders present can be simplified into one. To see this, assume signals x(t), y(t), and z(t) as shown and preserve the operation performed by the adders.
[image]
The final step is to simplify the first block of the circuit to convert it into a simplified negative feedback circuit as shown below.
[image]
[image]
Now, the equation for this block diagram can be written as:
$$
[R(s)(1 + G_1) - C(s)(H_1 - H_2)][G_2] = C(s)  
$$
$$
\frac{C(s)}{R(s)} = \frac{G_2(1 + G_1)}{1 + G_2(H_1 - H_2)}
$$